# Error when building Scala Maven project: Could not find or load main class scala_maven_executions.MainWithArgsInFile

Tags: scala, maven, scala-maven-plugin

Error when building a Maven project using `maven-scala-plugin`:

```
[ERROR] Error: Could not find or load main class scala_maven_executions.MainWithArgsInFile
```

Answer (score 0):

Then reason is that `settings.xml` file was copied from Windows to OS X without modification, however it contained Windows-specific local repository path:

```
<localRepository>C:\Users\<username>\.m2\repository</localRepository>
```

Should be changed to:

```
<localRepository>/Users/<username>/.m2/repository</localRepository>
```